# How to link to a function read in with automodule in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I read in a module (e.g. func.py) with the automodule function in Sphinx.

func.py could look like that

```
def funca(arg1):
    """ Docstring funca """
    return arg1
def funcb(arg2) 
     """ Docstring funcb """
    return arg2
```

I read func.py in with automodule like that.

```
.. automodule:: func
   :members:
```

At a different point in the documentation I want to include a link to for example to funca.

What is the best way of doing that? 
I have still some trouble understanding how the references in Sphinx work.

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was looking for.